# implementation of atoi in scala

Tags: scala

I've implemented `atoi` function as described in leetcode problem [string-to-integer-atoi](https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/).

I am looking for some feedback on writing this in a more scala native way and being able to include the requirement that:

> If the numerical value is out of the range of representable values,
>   INT_MAX (231 − 1) or INT_MIN (−231) is returned.

```
  object Solution {
    def myAtoi(str: String): Int = {

      val charMap = Map('1'->1, '2'->2, '3'->3, '4'->4, '5'->5, '6'->6, '7'->7, '8'->8, '9'->9, '0'-> 0)

      val keySet = charMap.keySet
      var num = 0
      var firstChar = -1
      var negFlag = false
      var zeroFlag = false

      var cleanStr = str.reverse.dropWhile(c => !charMap.contains(c) || c == '-' || c == ' ').trim

      for((c, i) <- cleanStr.view.zipWithIndex) {
        var summand = c match {
          case c if keySet.contains(c) => {
            if(firstChar == -1) firstChar = i
            charMap(c) * math.pow(10, i - firstChar).toInt
          }
          case '-' if(firstChar != -1) =>  {
            negFlag = true
            0
          }
          case _ => {
            zeroFlag = true
            0
          }
        }
        num += summand
      }
      if(zeroFlag) 0 else if(negFlag) num * -1 else num
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations about your code.

**incomplete** - As you've noted, it doesn't handle `Int` overflow. It also doesn't handle the optional leading `+` character.

**digit characters** - The variables `charMap` and `keyMap` are unnecessary. The `.isDigit` and `.asDigit` methods in the standard library provide the same functionality.

**Boolean logic** - Consider this Boolean test: `!charMap.contains(c) || c == '-' || c == ' '` It translates to "if c is not a digit OR if c is a dash OR if c is a space." But if c is a dash or space then it is already not a digit. The dash and space tests serve no purpose because no dash or space character would get beyond the digit test.

**unneeded vars** - There's no reason to make `cleanStr` or `summand` a `var`. Their initial values are never changed. In fact, you could just drop `summand` altogether and increment `num` directly.

```
num += (c match { ...//rest of code block
```

**excess braces** - In a `match{...}` every `case` statement ends the previous code block and starts a new one. Therefore wrapping the code block in `{` braces `}` is redundant and just adds visual clutter. In other words, this...

```
case x =>
  //code
  //here
```

...is cleaner than this...

```
case x => {
  //code
  //here
}
```

**style** - The use of so much mutation (i.e. `var`s instead of `val`s) makes it pretty clear that you are using the Scala language to write C code. This will change as you become more familiar with the Scala standard library, the tenants of Functional Programming, and the study of other Scala code.

Here, for example, is a Scala solution for the **atoi** challenge.

```
val numRE = "\\s*([+-]?)0*(\\d+).*".r

def myAtoi(str :String) :Int = str match {
  case numRE(signStr, numStr) =>
    val sign    = if (Option(signStr).contains("-")) -1 else 1
    val bailOut = if (sign < 0) Int.MinValue else Int.MaxValue
    if (numStr.length > 10) bailOut                      //too many digits
    else if (numStr.length < 10 || numStr < "2147483648")
      sign * numStr.foldLeft(0)(_*10 + _.asDigit)        //calculate return Int
    else bailOut
  case _ => 0  //input doesn't match the pattern
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain and also for your elegant solution :)